# How much memory take apache solr until commit

Tags: solr

I'm working on add document on the fly to solr, testing on live both method (soft and hard) takes approximate the same time (around of 5 seconds), so I decided use this configuration:

```
  <autoCommit> 
   <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
   <maxTime>86400000</maxTime> 
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
 </autoCommit>

   <autoSoftCommit> 
     <maxTime>300000</maxTime>  
   </autoSoftCommit>
```

Basically perform a hard commit when reach 10000 document without commit or have been passed 1 day, and perform softcommit each 5 minutes, I couldn't find any difference in time or cpu between hard and soft, is that right? I have a solr database of 1GiB.

My concern is regarding with the memory needed to do this, how do I do to estimate the memory needed with those 10000 document? or solr doesn't use any memory to hold it waiting the commit?

And how solr count the maxtime, from the first document add or the last? because my test on server appear to be from first but don't have any sense right?

Answer (score 0):

Solr doesn't hold any memory while after soft commit, one major difference between soft commit and hard commit is, soft commit is much faster since it only makes index changes visible and does not fsync index files or write a new index descriptor.

You can also read more about Soft commit and hard commit behavior here,

```
http://www.opensourceconnections.com/2013/04/25/understanding-solr-soft-commits-and-data-durability/
```

Comment: In my server soft or hard commit take the same time, it's on production so I incremented the memory just in case but my fear was because I readed here that soft commit eat a lot of memory until a hard commit happen but your answer clarify me, I'll continue experimented to try to find the best way to configurate solr.